# Dimension of sum of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am supposed to prove that

$$\dim(V + W)\le \dim V + \dim W$$

I kind of understand it intuitively.

I know that if $V ∩ W \neq \{0\}$ then 
$\dim(V + W) = \dim V + \dim W - \dim(V ∩ W )$.

And in that case $\dim(V+W)< \dim V + \dim W$.

And if $V \cap W = \{0\}$ then $\dim(V+W)=\dim V + \dim W$.

So I get what I needed to prove based on the dimension of the intersection of spaces $V$ and $W$. I am just wondering if this is enough of a proof, or I need to do something else for the proof to be complete.

Comment: What do you mean with "I know"

Comment: I mean that it is based on the theorem which says that $dim(V+W)=dimV+dimW−dim(V∩W)$

Comment: Then it is complete

Comment: @ivana14 What you say "you know" is all you need ( and it is true *even* if $\;\dim(V\cap W)=0\;$), as dimension of *anything* is non-negative...

Comment: @DonAntonio okay, than if I understand what you said correctly, I only need to add the condition that both $dimV$ and $dimW$ are positive. Right?

Comment: @ivana14 Not at all: the claim remains true even in the trivial case when one, or both, of the subspaces is the zero space.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, okay, I get it. Than my proof is okay, no need to add anything, thanks :)

Comment: Of course from equality-formula we immediately obtain inequality-formula but to get such a simple result it sufficient observe that linear closure of $v_1,\ldots ,v_s, w_1\ldots w_k$ equals $V+W$ and so the basis of  $V+W$ can be chosen from this system of vectors. Here $v_1,\ldots ,v_s$ is basis of $V$ and $w_1\ldots w_k$ is basis of $W.$

Comment: @Minz okay, that is interesting, but I am not sure I can see where you're getting at from there. Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: @ivana14 The all you need is read the definition of basis and the definition of sum of subspaces.